# Encrypted Array Won't Save in Eloquent Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm having an odd error with saving an encrypted array in Laravel. The model never updates even when save() is called.

**There are no console or SQL errors.
When the encryption is disabled, there are no errors and the model updates successfully.**

In a Controller, I'm calling the model like so:

```
$userData = UserData::where('user_id', $user_id)->first();
```

I then pull the array:

```
$encryptedData = $userData->app_data;
```

And I want to add to this array e.g.

```
$encryptedData['new'] = 'axy';
$encryptedData['time'] = time();
```

I then update the model and save it:

```
$userData->app_data = $encryptedData;

$userData->save();
```

However, here is where the problem starts. The model does not update. It remains as if nothing happens. Hence if I refresh(), I get the same data as if I had never added the two new entries. When I log it, it looks like this:

```
Array
(
[token] => xyz
[access_token] => abc 
)
```

After the addition of two new entries:

```
Array
(
[token] => xyz
[access_token] => abc 
[new] => 'axy'
[time] => 1234
)
```

And after the save() and refresh():

```
Array
(
[token] => xyz
[access_token] => abc 
)
```

The model looks like this:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;

class UserData extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [

        'user_id', 'app_data'

    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'user_id' => 'int',
        'app_data' => 'array'
    ];

    public function getAppDataAttribute($value)
    {
        try {

            return decrypt($value);
        } 

        catch (DecryptException $e) {

            return $value;

        }
    }

    public function setAppDataAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['app_data'] = encrypt($value);

    }

}
```

Why are my additions to the array not being saved?

Edit: The strangeness continues

If I call:

UserData::where('id', $userData->id)->update(['app_data' => $encryptedData]);

Then the model does update and **does not encrypt**, HOWEVER, when I refresh and log the new 'app_data' field, it is returned as a JSON string and not an array as before. I need to cast/decode it to an array each time I want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to look for.

1) The Laravel encrypter uses the app key.  Make sure you have one in your .env file.  If not, run `php artisan key:generate`

2) I assume the array is correctly formatted like this:

```
 Array
(
   'token' => 'xyz',   // You have a = here and no commas after any other value
   'access_token' => 'abc' 
)
```

3) Depending on what you are storing this as, you can test by serializing the array before encrypting it:

```
$arr = serialize($encryptedData);  // After you have added new data to the array
$userData->app_data = $arr;
$userData->save();
```

This is automatic in Laravel, but may give you a help hunting the bug.  Test with your mutator using `encryptString()` and manually `unserialize` / `decryptString()` to see if any odd behavior by stepping through the values as they are mutated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 

1) Yes, the key is valid. There are other encrypted fields that are not impacted by this bug.

2) The array is a typo on my part, I'll fix the opening question.

3) I stepped through and logged out all the encryption steps. When the array is updated, the new array reaches the model and generates a longer encrypted 'hash' but it is not saved.

Comment: Very odd.  I realize you said it works when not encrypted, so I didn't offer this... but are you using the same field, `app_data` to store?  Just thinking the mass assignment thing might be blocking if something odd there, though I can see it correct in your code.  I'm sorry I can't help more here, this is strange.  Going out on a limb, the last thing to suggest would be to change the variable name to something other than `app_data` to test.  Longshot, but possibly this is a Laravel specific field and interferes with encryption...

Comment: Thanks again. Interestly, if I call an update, the model does save but it becomes a JSON string when returned, ignoring the cast.